# Conditional Expectation

Tags: self-study, conditional-expectation

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ and $Z$ denote independent, real valued random variables and
$$Pr(Z=0) = 1-Pr(Z=1) = \alpha$$ for some $0<\alpha<1$ Define

$Y$ = $X_1 $ if $Z=0$

= $X_2$ if $Z=1$

(a) Suppose that $E(X_1)$ and $E(X_2)$ exist, does it follow that E(Y) exists?
(b) Assume that $E(|X_1|) < \infty $ and $E(|X_2|) < \infty $. Find $E(Y|X_1)$

This is NOT homework. This is from selfstudy. I would appreciate any kind of help. 
Intuitively, I feel that the answer for (a) is $E(X_1).\alpha+(1-\alpha).E(X_2)$ but I don't have any rigorous solution. For (b) I am totally confused not knowing even how to start. 
I don't even understand why the "$ < \infty $" is necessary.

I appreciate it.

Comment: **Hint:** express $Y$ as a linear combination of $X_1$ and $X_2$ with weights depending (linearly as well) on $Z$.

Comment: The [tag:homework] tag Wiki states this is "a routine question from a textbook, course, or test used for a class or self-study."  Your question fits the bill perfectly.

Comment: Some people say that "$E[X]$ exists" only if $E[|X|] < \infty$, others that "$E[X]$ is defined but unbounded" if _exactly one_ of the series or integral expressions for $E[X_+]$ and $E[X_-]$ is divergent and the other is convergent. Both groups agree that if both $E[X_+]$ and $E[X_-]$ are divergent (as happens for Cauchy random variables, for example), then $E[X]$ is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to notice that 
$$Y=(1-Z)X_1+ZX_2.$$
Then for the first question, we have $|Y|\leqslant |X_1|+|X_2|$.

For the second one, we have using independence and $\mathbb E(X_1\mid X_1)=1$,
$$\mathbb E(Y\mid X_1)=\mathbb E((1-Z)X_1\mid X_1)+\mathbb E(ZX_2\mid X_1)=X_1\mathbb E(1-Z)+(\mathbb EZ)(\mathbb EX_2).$$